# How can I fork data down different pipelines depending on some condition?

Tags: powershell

Is there anyway to send pipeline data down two different paths depending on some condition, without re-executing the upstream command? The notation is all wrong here, but this is what I'd like to see...

```
PS> Get-SomeInterestingData `
    | ?{ <condition> } `
    | %{ <positive> } `
    | %{ <negative> }
```

Could I do that with nested pipelines/expressions?

```
PS> Get-SomeInterestingData `
    | %{ 
        $_ | ?{ <condition> } | %{ <positive> } -or `
        $_ | ?{ -not <condition> } | %{ <positive> } 
    }
```

What if you don't have direct access to the data or data producing function, but you're receiving it from the pipeline? Say, as part of a script or function param block, like...

```
param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    $InputObject,
)
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you targeting?

Comment: Latest is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Switch` cmdlet.

```
Switch(Get-SomeInterestingData){
    {<positive>} {Do Stuff}
    {<negative>} {Do Other Stuff}
}
```

Comment: Oooh, I had forgotten about PowerShell's switch statement.

Comment: Except, you're not able to run a condition scriptblock in the parameters to a switch.

Comment: Sure you can. I do it all the time.

Comment: Oh, I see, you can use a scriptblock as the matcher part. Got it!

Comment: If you get the interesting data from the pipeline (as a function parameter or something), can you just wrap the switch in a process block or pass $Input?

Comment: You could pipe to a ForEach look and `Switch($_)` from there to process things one at a time, using a `ForEach` loop to iterate. `Switch` itself doesn't take pipeline info, so you'd have to build that logic yourself.

Comment: If your input for Switch is an array/collection it iterates, this has caused unexpected recursion and confusion in many of my scripts. Clever though, when you're expecting it.

Answer (score 5):

In PowerShell 4.0 and newer, you could use the `Where()` extension method in `Split` mode:

```
$Even,$Odd = @(1..10).Where({$_ % 2 -eq 0},'Split')
```

The input collection will be split into 2, those items satisfying the filter, and those that don't. You can then work on each, without defining the input collection again

Comment: Came here to post this. The `.Where()` method has some really cool features.

Comment: And this is why I love this site. Now I have something new to go look into.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician There's an overload that takes a 3rd argument as well, but I'll encourage you to explore on your own ;-) second is `[System.Management.Automation.WhereOperatorSelectionMode]`

Comment: Already found and read most of [Boe's write-up](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/11/26/checking-out-the-where-and-foreach-operators-in-powershell-v4/) on it. Really good stuff. Reminds me that there's always more to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly not in the way you hope.

Technically this is doing what you describe though; albeit unexciting:

```
1..10 | %{
    if ($_ % 2 -eq 0) { #even pipeline
        $_ | write-host -ForegroundColor green #add whatever you want to happen on this pipeline instead of write-host 
    } else { #odd pipeline
        $_ | write-host -ForegroundColor cyan #add whatever you want to happen on this pipeline instead of write-host
    }
}
```

---

If you want something funkier, this will work too; though in many scenarios is more confusing:

```
$PipelineIfTrue = {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)][PSObject]$InputObject)
    process {
        $InputObject | write-host -ForegroundColor green
    }
}
$PipelineIfFalse = {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)][PSObject]$InputObject)
    process {
        $InputObject | write-host -ForegroundColor cyan
    }
}

1..10 | %{$_ | &@($PipelineIfFalse, $PipelineIfTrue)[($_ % 2 -eq 0)]}
```

i.e. create a couple of script blocks which take pipeline input; one which defines what to do if your condition evaluates to true, one for false.

We stick those in an array and use the condition's result to index that array; i.e. if false (index=0) we return the `PipelineIfFalse` script; if true (index=1) we return `PipelineIfTrue`.

The ampersand says to execute this script, and given we're pipeing the current value to this script, that then becomes an argument to this anonymous function's pipeline.

---

**Update**

Because I'm a sadist, I carried on.  You could do this:

```
1..10 | Fork-Pipeline {$_ % 2 -eq 0} `
    { Write-Host -ForegroundColor green } `
    { Write-Host -ForegroundColor cyan }
```

or

```
1..10 | Fork-Pipeline `
    -If {$_ % 2 -eq 0} `
    -Then { Write-Host -ForegroundColor green } `
    -Else { Write-Host -ForegroundColor cyan }
```

Here's the Cmdlet:

```
function Fork-Pipeline {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true)]
        [PSObject]$InputObject
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position=0)]
        [Alias('If')]
        [ScriptBlock]$Condition
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position=1)]
        [Alias('Then')]
        [ScriptBlock]$PiplineIfTrue
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position=2)]
        [Alias('Else')]
        [ScriptBlock]$PiplineIfFalse
    )
    begin {
        #[string]$template = '[CmdletBinding()]param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$InputObject)process{{$InputObject | {0}}}'
        [string]$template = '$_ | {0}' #much simpler version of the above
        $FunctionIfTrue = [scriptblock]::Create($template -f $PiplineIfTrue.ToString())
        $FunctionIfFalse = [scriptblock]::Create($template -f $PiplineIfFalse.ToString())
    }
    process {
        if (&$Condition) {
            $InputObject | &$FunctionIfTrue
        } else {
            $InputObject | &$FunctionIfFalse
        }
    }
}
```

I don't recommend that approach though; it's not going to perform amazingly well, and most likely will confuse anyone who's used to dealing with normal PS pipelines.  Just good for academic fun.

Comment: Ah, the old "if-statement"! I had forgotten about that because I'm so used to pipelining in PowerShell.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely funkier and probably not worth the effort to understand it :)